# Greater than or equals comparison against an enum with Fluent Validation?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, fluentvalidation

Ok, let's say I'm trying to validate an object conditionally based upon the value of an enum, how can I do that?

Here's a sample call to validate the object.

```
MyObjectValidator validator = new MyObjectValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(new MyObject());
```

Here's a sample of a class with an Enum Value.

```
public class MyObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<MyObject>
{

    public MyObjectValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.anEnum).Equal(MyObject.MyEnum.First).SetValidator(new FirstValidator());
    }

}

public class FirstValidator : AbstractValidator<MyObject>
{

    public FirstValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.someDecimal).Equal(1).WithMessage("Decimal must equal 5 with anEnum set to First");
    }

}

public class MyObject
{

    public enum MyEnum : int
    {
        First = 0,
        Second = 1,
        Third = 2
    }

    public decimal someDecimal { get; set; }
    public MyEnum anEnum { get; set; }

    public MyObject()
    {
        anEnum = MyEnum.First;
        someDecimal = 5;
    }
}
```

This particular example throws the message: "The validator 'FirstValidator' cannot validate members of type 'MyEnum' - the types are not compatible."

After some editing, I came up with a wrapper to do what I'm hoping, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution.  I replaced MyObjectValidator with

```
public MyObjectValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.anEnum).SetValidator(new ValidatorWrapper<MyObject>()).When(x => x.anEnum == MyObject.MyEnum.First);
}
```

And added a validator wrapper

```
public class ValidatorWrapper<T> : PropertyValidator
{

    public ValidatorWrapper() : base("Validator Message")
    {
    }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        MyObject myObj = (MyObject)context.Instance;
        FirstValidator validator = new FirstValidator();
        ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(myObj);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to reference the inner context without having to provide the propertyvalidator wrapper such that I can conditionally validate a number of rules based upon an enum value?

Comment: Fluent Validation provides a validator called `Equal()`, not `Equals()`.

Comment: And what is `MyFirstEnumValidator`? A short but *complete* example would really help here...

Comment: I've asked this question on the Fluent Validation discussion list as well:  http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/279677

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're seeing ("The validator 'FirstValidator' cannot validate members of type 'MyEnum' - the types are not compatible") is because by using SetValidator you're trying to validate the anEnum *property* with FirstValidator (which can only validate instances of MyObject) - this isn't the correct approach. If you want to trigger rules based on the enum property, you need to use FluentValidation's support for conditions.

If you've only got a single rule to which you want to apply the condition, then you can do this:

```
public class MyObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<MyObject> {

  public MyObjectValidator() {
      RuleFor(x => x.someDecimal).Equal(1).When(x => x.anEnum == MyObject.MyEnum.First);
  }

}
```

...alternatively, if you want to apply the same condition to multiple rules, you can use a single condition using the top-level When method:

```
public class MyObjectValidator : AbstractValidator<MyObject> {

    public MyObjectValidator() {
        When(x => x.anEnum == MyObject.MyEnum.First, () => {
            RuleFor(x => x.someDecimal).Equal(1);
            //other rules can go here
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the CLR's `Object.Equals()`, you need to use `Equal()` or whatever else the library provides.

Comment: This was a typo in the original example